# Redirect to LogOff Page in case of Failure in Ajax call

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, struts2

I want to redirect my request to LogOff page, if there is any error in the Struts2 Action class.
I am doing a ajax call to struts action from db.jsp, where I am validating the session variables.
I want user to get ajax response on db.jsp, if session is validated, else redirect to logoff.jsp.

My Ajax call from db.jsp is like :

```
  $.ajax({
          type : "POST",
          url: "startapp",
          data:{ processDateInput: processDate,secretToken:tokenLocal},
          dataType: "json",
          async: true,
          success: function(result) {
                                var od = JSON.stringify(result); 
                                var obj = JSON.parse(od);
                                var i = 0;
                                console.log(od);
                                }
});
```

I am validating the  ere if the session is validated, send the response back to Ajax, else redirect to LogOffRedirection.jsp page from where user is logged off from the application:

```
    public class StartAppAction extends ActionSupport {

        private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(StartAppAction.class
                .getName());

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -367986889632883043L;
        private final static String SUCCESS = "success";
        private final static String FAILURE = "failure";

        // private ProcessDate pd = new ProcessDate();

        private Object od;
        private String processDateInput = null;
        private String secretToken=null;

        public String execute() throws Exception {

            HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
            HttpServletResponse response = ServletActionContext.getResponse();
    try{
                if(null!=request.getSession().getAttribute("sesStrUID") && null!=secretToken){
                    if(!secretToken.trim().equals(request.getSession().getAttribute("sesStrUID").toString().trim())){
                        return FAILURE;

                    }

                   }
               }
               catch (Exception e) {
                   logger.error("Exception in token verification in Pre con action");
               }
        return SUCCESS;
        }
public String getProcessDateInput() {
        return processDateInput;
    }

    public void setProcessDateInput(String processDateInput) {
        this.processDateInput = processDateInput;
    }

    public Object getOd() {
        return od;
    }

    public void setOd(Object od) {
        this.od = od;
    }

    public String getSecretToken() {
        return secretToken;
    }

    public void setSecretToken(String secretToken) {
        this.secretToken = secretToken;
    }
```

Struts.xml I have given as :

```
<action name="startapp" class="com.ge.wd.action.StartAppAction">
            <result name= "success" type="json"></result>
            <result name="failure">/jsp/LogOffRedirection.jsp</result>
        </action>
```

It is not working, should it work like this?
Or do we have anything else to acheive the same in Struts2.

Comment: Your ajax call always expect to receive the json result, so if anything goes wrong on the server, the javascript in the client do not know any thing about it. So always send json from your action and put some flags in it, so you can read and work on it in the client javascript, as code sample by @Justin Russo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of redirecting from the server, which wouldn't work since you are doing an Asynchronous call using AJAX.  What you need to do is redirect from your success method, by sending a value which specifies the error condition you want to redirect for.  In the case below, I'm passing a "RedirectURL" as a root member of the returned JSON object.  If it exists, then you would redirect.

For example...

```
$.ajax({
      type : "POST",
      url: "startapp",
      data:{ processDateInput: processDate,secretToken:tokenLocal},
      dataType: "json",
      async: true,
      success: function(result) {
                            var od = JSON.stringify(result); 
                            var obj = JSON.parse(od);
                            var i = 0;
                            console.log(od);
                            if(obj.redirectUrl){
                                 window.location(obj.redirectUrl);
                            }
      }
});
```

You can also do this in the 'fail' method of your call, by throwing an exception from the server.  This way, ALL exceptions will redirect to the page you wish.

```
   $.ajax({
          type : "POST",
          url: "startapp",
          data:{ processDateInput: processDate,secretToken:tokenLocal},
          dataType: "json",
          async: true,
          success: function(result) {
                                var od = JSON.stringify(result); 
                                var obj = JSON.parse(od);
                                var i = 0;
                                console.log(od);
          },
          fail: function(ex) {
              window.location(ExceptionRedirectUrl); //ExceptionRedirectUrl would be a global constant.
          }
    });
```